# php search imap emails in reply to header

Tags: php, email, search, imap, crm

I have to search all email sent and from a specific email address with php.
In some emails the email are from different sites and the address is in the reply-to header.
In the sent folder is simple, I'm using the imap_search funcion:

```
$imapResult= imap_search($imapStream,'TO info@email.com');
```

Retrieve the message from a specific email address is also simple:

```
$imapResult= imap_search($imapStream,'FROM info@email.com');
```

The problem is to retrieve the message from an address via other webservices, having from header the email of another site, and the email of the client in the reply-to header.

A solution is parse the header of all emails in inbox but it will be too slowly.

What is the faster method to search the inbox email with php to retrieve the messages from a email in **reply-to header**?

Comment: I would suggest doing just that, offloading all your emails to a database where you can maintain the data the way you want and then use that to search the data, both from (including the reply-to) and to. A database would be much faster than IMAP anyway.

Comment: Shure, but I have to create a script to download and update all the email in the database, I can wait many seconds to have the result, but I want to look directly in imap folder...

Comment: The point of offloading it to a database on reception is that you do the IMAP operation once and then have the organized data, but if this works for you - fine.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using the text option

```
$imapResult= imap_search($imapStream,'TEXT "info@email.com"');
```

Now I find in the inbox all the emails from the client.
It's impossible another client send me an email with inside the text the email address of onother people....